# how to check if a connection to a database exists in sqlite using java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, database-connection, repository-pattern

I have the folowing dbConnection

```
public class DBConnection {

    protected Statement statement;
    protected Connection connection = null;

    public DBConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\ion\\Desktop\\sample.db");
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

                statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id STRING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                        + "name STRING, email STRING UNIQUE, password STRING)");

                statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (id STRING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                        + "text STRING, subject STRING, dateMessage Date, parrentMessageId String , personId String, "
                        + "categoryId String,"
                        + " FOREIGN KEY(personId) REFERENCES person(id),FOREIGN KEY(categoryId) REFERENCES category(id))");

                statement.executeUpdate(
                        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (id STRING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + "name STRING)");



        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but if I use in a Servlet like this

```
String id = personService.getIdByEmail(email);

        message.setPersonId(id);
        messageService.persist(message);
```

and I call twice different services which  calls different repositories (personRep and messageRep both extend this DbConnection class) It's giving me `"database is locked"`

How do I check if a connection already exists ? Please help me ..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two devices for and call two service at the same time. So, Server will create two thread and serve the two request. This two head will open two connection at the same time. and  using this connection, one the thread will execute the  SQL statement which has CREATE table command. this are DDL expression. SO one the thread get the Database lock and other thread will bottleneck and give exception like 'database is lock'.

You can use synchronisation so that only one thread will be allowed to execute the code. other have wait until finish.

more detail https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked

Comment: Something like that ? synchronized (lock1) {
   
  
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\ion\\Desktop\\sample.db");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.setQueryTimeout(30);